# Need help identifying extra large Lego figure from 2003

Tags: minifigures, minifigure-identification

I came across these LEGO figures at an estate sale and have had no luck trying to find out what they are called.

They are much larger than a regular minifig but have a shaped foot plate to attach to regular sized Legos. They can be squeezed down and compressed and then pop back up.

Top and bottom are two different pieces and inside there are screws visible. Only markings are "LEGO" on front shirt and "48379" and "2003" on bottom of foot plate. Thinking they were not part of a set but a promo item or accessory.

[image: Lego comparison]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

48379 is the part number for the torso piece. 2003 would be the copyright date for the LEGO trademark.

They are both promotional items which were distributed with McDonald's Happy Meals.

[image]

**Bricklink:** [7923-1](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=7923-1) (White Soccer Player #4)

[image]

**Bricklink:** [7917-1](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=7917-1) (Blue Basketball Player #22)